# How to apply web middleware for 404 page?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a problem getting auth user in navbar template in laravel 5.2 when 404 occurs.
the reason is I can not apply web middleware to 404 page.

Please let me know how to get auth user when NotFoundHttpException occurs

Comment: you mean set a 404 page?

Comment: no I have made 404.blade.php but in that page I am not able to access auth user

Comment: A duplicate question has answers regarding yours.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42418507/laravel-cant-see-if-a-user-is-logged-in-on-404-error-page

However, the practices in the answers caused to emerge a new question which you can see below.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48693874/laravel-and-issues-regarding-authentication-and-login-validation