# Laravel can't see if a user is logged in on 404 error page

Tags: laravel

I have created a custom 404 error page and I am using my app.layout to wrap it.

But it's strange because when i get 404 error page even though I'm logged in the Login and Register links are seen. Why is that?

[image]

#### update

when i log in on my page and write non existing route i get my 404 page with extended layout but it seems like Laravel doesn't have access to Auth::class and it doesn't see if a user is logged in or not.

So instead of seeing Logout link i see "Login" and "Register" links

Comment: because your 404 layout extends that layout which has those links

Comment: But I am logged in....and i have a 403 page also and on 403 error page the Login link and register links are not visible...

Comment: @msonowal did you vote me down? can you at least say why

Comment: I didnt vote down

Comment: can you recreate the problem. just wrap up 404 error page with layout and login and see if you have login and register or only logout link

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check if your app.layout included a nav partial.

a layout html like this :

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
 <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
 @include('partials.crumble_head')
 <!-- Main content -->
 <section class="content">
  @yield('content')
 </section>
 <!-- /.content -->
</div>
```

if your content page extends this layout, then partial will not disapear

**Hi, The answer needs to be updated based on what we discussed.**

```
Open app/Http/Kernel.php. Add below block to the $middleware

    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
```

so your code should like this:

```
/**
 * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
 *
 * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
];
```

Now you should be able to access Auth in your views/errors/404.blade page. Make sure you put a '\ ' before Auth. For Eg:

```
{{\Auth::user()->name}}
```

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/getting-authuser-on-custom-404-page

Comment: it is not about disappearing but about that it is showing login and register instead of logout

Comment: Something is different with 404 error page in laravel and i don't get it what. It's like on that page laravel doesn't see if a user is logged in or not

Comment: @ray_cheng can you recreate the problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36417812/how-to-apply-web-middleware-for-404-page   this is the same question

Comment: I have sent you a request

Answer (score 13):

Add this below to `/routes/web.php`:

```
Route::fallback(function(){
    return view('errors.404');
});
```

and add a new file `/resources/views/errors/404.blade.php`:

```
Nothing here {{ Auth::user()->name }}: 404!
```

Of course, you can change this template to extend any template you want to use.

Available from [v5.5.5](https://github.com/laravel/framework/releases/tag/v5.5.5)

Comment: This is the method to get it to work with the least amount of work so far.

Comment: This seemed to help ! Thank you. Still, I don't understand why it behaves like that since I have extended my layout in the custom errors/404.blade.php

Answer (score 0):

I've found another situation where this happens.

If you have switched a site to SSL and set the Session cookie "Secure" flag to `true`, and don't have a forced redirect non-ssl > ssl (htaccess/whatever). If you were logged into the non-ssl site previously with the "remember" option, then the remember cookie "Secure" flag will still be `false`.

In the case where you browse the non-ssl site then the Session cookie won't stick because you're not on SSL, so the user will effectively get a new session created on every request by the remember cookie which isn't "Secure". So you will appear to be logged in, except when you see a 404 where you will appear to be logged out (for whatever reason).